# Save drawn chart in xamarin

Tags: xamarin

I'm have a large chart in scrollWiew using Grid in xamarin. Drawing this chart take much time. Is it possible to draw scrollView and show it next time without wasting so much time to draw it again?

```
  <ScrollView x:Name="scroll"
                Orientation="Horizontal">
      <Grid x:Name="chart"
            Grid.Row="0">
      </Grid>
    </ScrollView>
```